# In Rails 6, how do you use asset_path in a js.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I have an image located here:

`app/assets/images/tokens/zombies/Shambler.png`

When I type in rails console the command:

`helper.asset_path("tokens/zombies/Shambler.png")`

It returns:

`/assets/tokens/zombies/Shambler-(Fingerprint).png`

However, when I use this line in my code:

`token.src = '<%= asset_path("tokens/zombies/Shambler.png") %>';`

It returns:

```
bootstrap:83 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js):
Error: rails-erb-loader failed with code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (neptune07289825/Projects/NarrativeDice/node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js:128)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259)
    at Object../app/javascript/packs/map.js.erb (bootstrap:83)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

Based on my research, I understand this to mean that erb-loader has checked and found no asset in the designated asset path. I just don't understand why, since I am able to find it in the console, it's clearly in the default pipeline and I haven't changed the manifest.

Can someone tell me how to do this using a js.erb file?

Answer (score -1):

The helper to manage images in an erb file is `image_path` or `image_url`
,it depend where you store your image.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html